# Connecting Unity3d to a 4.0 .net framework API visual studio program

Tags: c#, api, sockets, unity-game-engine, lego-mindstorms

I have a Lego EV3. I am using the API to work with C# in visual studio.

I tried and it looks like the only way to use unity3d with the EV3 is using two programs and having them communicate.

Unity uses a 2.0 framework so `async` functions do not work(I'm pretty sure, if anyone can get `async` on unity then that would be better).

So I'm trying to use sockets and I believe I'm all good with the code but when I run both my computer is actively refusing the connection.

Firewall is down, running as admin.

So how do I fix my socket problem so I can communicate  with unity3d or how do I communicate with unity3d?

Sorry for how sloppy the code is but this is my main code that i'm working on so I run this and I control my robot but can't send data to my program running in unity3d.

Go thru code  and the //7777777777777777777777777777777777 will show where it stops when I click button 3 and says actively rejected by my computer

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Lego.Ev3.Core;
using Lego.Ev3.Desktop;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;

using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace leeeego
{
    public class LegoMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Brick _brick;
    int _forward = 40;
    int _backward = 30;
    uint _time = 3000;

    public float moveSpeed;

    private Vector3 input;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        input = new Vector3(2, 0, 2);
        //_brick = new Brick(new UsbCommunication());
        // _brick.BrickChanged += _brick_BrickChanged;
        //  _brick.ConnectAsync();
        //  _brick.DirectCommand.PlayToneAsync(100, 1000, 300);
    }

    //private void _brick_BrickChanged(object sender, BrickChangedEventArgs e)
    //{

    //}
}

}
namespace TheBrick
{
public class LegoMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Brick _brick;
    int _forward = 40;
    int _backward = 30;
    uint _time = 3000;

    public float moveSpeed;

    private Vector3 input;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        //_brick = new Brick(new UsbCommunication());
        // _brick.BrickChanged += _brick_BrickChanged;
        //  _brick.ConnectAsync();
        //  _brick.DirectCommand.PlayToneAsync(100, 1000, 300);
    }

    //private void _brick_BrickChanged(object sender, BrickChangedEventArgs e)
    //{

    //}
}
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Brick _brick;
    int _forward = 50;
    int _backward = 30;
    uint _time = 3000;
    int _x = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _brick = new Brick(new UsbCommunication());
        _brick.BrickChanged += _brick_BrickChanged;
        await _brick.ConnectAsync();
        await _brick.DirectCommand.PlayToneAsync(10, 1000, 300);



        TheBrick.Database1DataSet database1DataSet = ((TheBrick.Database1DataSet)(this.FindResource("database1DataSet")));
        // Load data into the table Table. You can modify this code as needed.
        TheBrick.Database1DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter database1DataSetTableTableAdapter = new TheBrick.Database1DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter();
        database1DataSetTableTableAdapter.Fill(database1DataSet.Table);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource tableViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("tableViewSource")));
        tableViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
    }

    private void _brick_BrickChanged(object sender, BrickChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private async void Move_up_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _brick = new Brick(new UsbCommunication());
        _brick.BrickChanged += _brick_BrickChanged;
        await _brick.ConnectAsync();
        await _brick.DirectCommand.PlayToneAsync(100, 1000, 300);
    }

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await _brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(OutputPort.B | OutputPort.C, _forward, _time, false);
        _x += 1;
        //label = _x;
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int a = Score.instace.CurrentScore;
        int b = 10;
        if (a == b)
        {
            await _brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(OutputPort.B | OutputPort.C, _forward, _time, false);
        }
    }


    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::TheBrick.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO Table (moveLego,noiseLego) values(" + txtMove.Text + "," + txtNoise.Text + ")";
            SqlCommand exesql = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            cn.Open();
            exesql.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
        _forward = Convert.ToInt32(txtMove.Text);
        _time = Convert.ToUInt32(txtNoise.Text);

        await _brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync       (OutputPort.B     | OutputPort.C, _forward, _time, false);
    }

    private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    string serverIP = "localhost";
    int port = 8080;

    private async void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIP, port);//777777777777777777777777

            int bytecount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(txtMove.Text);

            byte[] sendData = new byte[bytecount];

            sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtMove.Text);

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);

            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            _forward = Convert.ToInt32(txtMove.Text);
            _time = Convert.ToUInt32(txtNoise.Text);

            await _brick.DirectCommand.TurnMotorAtPowerForTimeAsync(OutputPort.B | OutputPort.C, _forward, _time, false);

        }




    }
    }
}`
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Any code examples of what is currently bogging you down?

Comment: Unity uses Mono which is a subset of dotnet4.0 but only gaurentees implementation of up to 2.0.  This is why linq request work

Comment: You can try to use async/await unofficially via tools such as this, https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncBridge.Net35/ No warranty though.

Comment: If you do want to check socket related things, learn how to use tools such as Wireshark and analyze the network packets.

Comment: Really I can't find a video to help with the socket and I have watched prob more than 25 by now. So that why I ask but I only care about how to send my sensor data which isn't one here to my program in Unity which(from my belief) only excepts data from .net 2.0 "using"

Comment: I know the socket is a localhost error but can't find how to fix that or make a localhost everyone has forgotten how because they say it was so long ago haha

Answer (score 0):

Unity has as Security protocol of some sort. So you can only connect Unity programs. Photon server is a possible way around or wrappers on Unity to work with higher C#